# A QR-code doesn't appear in the report. Why?

Tags: xml, report, qr-code, odoo, odoo-8

I tried to print a simple QR code image and I couldn't get it. I used the [code that I found in the documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/reports.html#barcodes) and it didn't work. Do I need anything else? I have the `reportlabs` library installed.

```
<img t-att-src="'/report/barcode/QR/%s' % 'My text in qr code'" />

<img t-att-src="'/report/barcode/?type=%s&amp;value=%s&amp;width=%s&amp;height=%s'%('QR', 'text', 200, 200)"/>
```

I checked the log file and I find this error:

```
    2015-07-13 12:01:09,305 28260 INFO wiretec_01 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jul/2015 12:01:09] "GET /report/barcode/QR/My%20text%20in%20qr%20code HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2015-07-13 12:01:09,322 28260 ERROR wiretec_01 werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo8/openerp/service/server.py", line 281, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/opt/odoo8/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 216, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo8/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 202, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo8/openerp/http.py", line 1280, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo8/openerp/http.py", line 1254, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo8/openerp/http.py", line 1421, in dispatch
    result = ir_http._dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 130, in _dispatch
    return self._handle_exception(e)
  File "/opt/odoo8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 100, in _handle_exception
    return request._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo8/openerp/http.py", line 659, in _handle_exception
    return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 126, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo8/openerp/http.py", line 677, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo8/openerp/http.py", line 303, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/openerp/http.py", line 300, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo8/openerp/http.py", line 796, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo8/openerp/http.py", line 396, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo8/modules/addons/report/controllers/main.py", line 94, in report_barcode
    barcode = barcode.asString('png')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/graphics/shapes.py", line 830, in asString
    rl_config.showBoundary),**_extraKW(self,'_renderPM_',**kw))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPM.py", line 660, in drawToString
    drawToFile(d,s,fmt=fmt, dpi=dpi, bg=bg, configPIL=configPIL)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPM.py", line 655, in drawToFile
    c = drawToPMCanvas(d, dpi=dpi, bg=bg, configPIL=configPIL, showBoundary=showBoundary)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPM.py", line 641, in drawToPMCanvas
    draw(d, c, 0, 0, showBoundary=showBoundary)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPM.py", line 50, in draw
    R.draw(renderScaledDrawing(drawing), canvas, x, y, showBoundary=showBoundary)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderbase.py", line 198, in draw
    self.initState(x,y)  #this is the push()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPM.py", line 99, in initState
    self.applyState()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPM.py", line 93, in applyState
    self._canvas.setFont(s['fontName'], s['fontSize'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPM.py", line 374, in setFont
    _setFont(self._gs,fontName,fontSize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPM.py", line 227, in _setFont
    raise RenderPMError("Can't setFont(%s) missing the T1 files?\nOriginally %s: %s" % (fontName,s1,s2))
RenderPMError: Can't setFont(Times-Roman) missing the T1 files?
Originally <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: makeT1Font() argument 2 must be string, not None
```

I have the package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` installed as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution in the Odoo forum, [here](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/help-1/question/renderpmerror-cant-setfont-times-roman-missing-the-t1-files-29688):

Download and uncompress in `/path/to/your/python/site-packages/reportlab/fonts` these file

http://www.reportlab.com/ftp/fonts/pfbfer.zip

Restart server and try